# How to switch element back to its original color after focus is switched to next element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I render a list of items that are `contentEditable`. When I switch focus to the second element, the first element is still white. I thought the color switch statement (using `this.state.active` check) would work but clearly, I'm lacking in my thinking here. How would you go about it? Must I implement the logic in `Comments` component/container instead?

[image]

In parent container **comments.tsx**, I render the comments with;

```js
<div className="comments">
                    <div>
                        {comments.map((value, key) => {
                            return (   
                                    <Comment key={key} profile={this.state.profile} data={value}/>
                                );
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and in **comment.tsx**, I have;

```js
interface IProps {
        key: number;
        profile: IProfile;
        data: object;
    }
    
    export class Comment extends React.Component<IProps, any> {
        constructor(props: IProps) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                editableColor: 'green',
                active:false
            }
        }
    
        editReview = (e, data) => {
            let { _id, user, comm } = data;       
            this.setState({active: true}, function () {
                this.state.active ? this.setState({editableColor:'#ffffff'}) : this.setState({editableColor:'green'});
            });    
        }
    
        render() {
            let { key, profile, data } = this.props;

            return(
                <div className="col-8 comment">
            
                    <p id="comment" contentEditable style={{backgroundColor: this.state.editableColor}} 
                          onFocus={(e) => this.editReview(e, data)}
                    >
                        {data['comm']}   
                    </p>
                
                    <button onClick={(e) => this.update(e, data)}>Update</button>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Been a while since I tinkered with React, but have you read the React FAQ about sending functions to setState instead of objects, as there is a major difference  in regards whether you get a current value/state of an object or not? setState calls are async and your expected values are in many cases "old" unless you return a function with a state.value instead of this.state.value, which only get updated AFTER render, after every component has called setState.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was actually easy. As always I should have passed `editableColor` as a prop to `Component` in **comments.tsx**

```
<Comment key={key} profile={this.state.profile} data={value} editableColor={'green'}/>
```

Pull it out as a prop in **comment.tsx**

```
let { key, profile, data, editableColor } = this.props;
```

Switch out the color depending on focus/blur

```
editReview = (e, data) => {
    this.setState({active: true});
}

<p 
    id="comment" 
    contentEditable 
    style={{backgroundColor: this.state.active ? editableColor='#ffffff' : editableColor}} 
    onFocus={(e) => this.editReview(e, data)}
    onBlur={ () => this.setState({ active: false }) }
>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you never come back from the active state, you should implement an `onBlur` event handler to revert `state.active` to false:

```
...
<p
  id="comment"
  contentEditable style={{backgroundColor: this.state.editableColor}} 
  onFocus={(e) => this.editReview(e, data)}
  onBlur={ () => this.setState({ active: false }) }
>
  {data['comm']}   
</p>
...
```

Comment: doesn't look like it's working. No change in outcome.

Comment: Would you try to edit your answer adding a code snippet to test it?